# Using while loops how do I calculate a sum between two values up to and including those values?

Tags: while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please type two numbers ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();
        int b = keyboard.nextInt();
        int sum = 0; 
        if (a <= b) {
            while (a <= b) {
                sum += a;
                a--;
            }
        }
        else if (b <= a) {
            while (b <= a) {
                sum += a;
                a++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The sum of the numbers between " + a + " and " + b + " is " + sum);
    }
}
```

The Main Problem i am having with this is it is giving me the sum -1073741823 for every input. What is supposed to happen is when I input two values say 1 first then 4 it should add 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 together and if the first input is larger than the second input like 4 first then 1 it would go 4 + 3 + 2 + 1. I don't understand why it is not doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sum the numbers in the range [a,b], inclusive, try the following.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please type two numbers ");
    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int sum = 0; 

    int s = Math.min(a, b);
    int e = Math.max(a, b);

    while (s <= e) {
      sum += s;
      s++;
    }

    System.out.print("The sum of the numbers between " + a + " and " + b + " is " + sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, but I have to use while loops. I'm studying my old tests for an exam tomorrow and that is what it says.

Comment: Sorry! I will change my solution.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't decrement in first `while loop` you should increment

instead of `a--;` put `a++;`

instead of `while (b <= a) {` put  `while (b >= a) {`

All together

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please type two numbers ");
        int a = keyboard.nextInt();
        int b = keyboard.nextInt();
        int sum = 0; 
        if (a <= b) {
            while (a <= b) {
                sum += a;
                a++;
            }
        }
        else if (b <= a) {
            while (b >= a) {
                sum += b;
                b--;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The sum of the numbers between " + a + " and " + b + " is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do as you ask wouldn't both while loops just mean the same thing?

Comment: don't you think in your program this 1 + 2 + 3 + 4  and 4+3+2+1 doesn't mean same thing

Comment: I just need to be able to go both ways that's what i'm saying like from a to b, but backwards as well from b to a.

Comment: in your second while loop instead of this sum += a;a++; add this sum+=b;b--;

Comment: check the answer once again

Comment: I managed to get the sum right now for both cases my only problem now is that when it prints a and b now it prints the wrong a and b values but the right sum

Comment: is the sum right? are you talking about this statement System.out.print(

Comment: ----jGRASP exec: java Q6

Please type two numbers 2 4
The sum of the numbers between 5 and 4 is 9
 ----jGRASP: operation complete. It does this instead of typing 2 and 4 it does 5 and 4.

Comment: Yes just the values of a and b are wrong in the print statement I assume it is giving me the new a value rather than the original a value of 2. Could i cheat a little and do the print statement System.out.print("The sum of the numbers between " + a + " and " + b + " is ") above my while loops then below just go system.out.print(sum); ?

Comment: yes, but put this statement "System.out.print(" in while loops to track values of a and b

Comment: I managed to get it. It could probably be a bit simpler, but i really appreciate the help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch `a--` and `a++`. You simply have your cases switched.

The way you have it now, if `a` is 1 and `b` is 4, it will go into the first if/while set, where it will add the first `a` to `sum`, but then decrement `a`, moving it farther from `b`, not closer. So, your loop will continue until `a` overflows. Probably not what you wanted.

A similar sort of thing happens if `b` is less than `a` to begin with.

Also, as @rafael-rendon-pablo's example shows, there are plenty of other ways to rewrite the code.